# Creating a dictionary from a csv file while iterating through rows

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, iteration, row

I need to create a function that takes a csv file as input and generates a dictionary. The csv files that are inputted into the function could be of different number of rows and columns. The function should be able to compensate for this.

An example of a csv file that could be used would be:

```
book.title,book.year,book.author

Godel Escher Bach, 1979, Douglas Hofstadter

What if?, 2014, Randall Munroe

Thing Explainer, 2015, Randall Munroe

Alan Turing: The Enigma, 2014, Andrew Hodges
```

I need every item in the first line of the csv file to be a key in the dictionary and then have each item the row under that key to be placed into a list of values.

so the output for the example csv file given would be:

```
my_dict = { 'book.title': [Godel Escher Bach, What if?, Thing Explainer, Alan Turing: The Enigma,], 'book.year': [1979, 2014, 2015, 2014], 'book.author': [Douglas Hofstadter, Randall Munroe, Randall Munroe, Andrew Hodges]}
```

Comment: What did you come up with so far and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Try `defaultdict` and `dictreader` to read csv file-

```
import csv
from collections import  defaultdict
data = defaultdict(list)


with open(r"C:\bk.csv",'rb') as f:
    rd = csv.DictReader(f)
    for i in rd:
        for j in i.keys():
            data[j].append(i[j])
print {k:v for k,v in data.items()}
```

Output-

```
{'book.year': ['1979', '2014', '2015', '2014'], 'book.title': ['Godel Escher Bach', 'What if?', 'Thing Explainer', 'Alan Turing: The Enigma'], 'book.author': [' Douglas Hofstadter', ' Randall Munroe', ' Randall Munroe', ' Andrew Hodges']}
```

N.B. I assumed no blank row in the csv file.